# "ArgumentOutOfRangeException" loading any razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

So I've been having some strange issues with an ASP.NET Core app of mine, whenever I load any Razor page, or do anything in relation to Razor code, I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException thrown at me.

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: version
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpParseOptions.WithLanguageVersion(LanguageVersion version)
```

Despite intense Googling, I've not been able to find anything related to the issue I'm having. No amounts of moving files around, reinstalling or restoring of nuget packages has helped.

I've also tried re-targeting different C# and .NET Framework versions, to no avail.

Here's the basic stack trace, I don't really see it being of much use, but hey.

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: version
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpParseOptions.WithLanguageVersion(LanguageVersion version)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DependencyContextRazorViewEngineOptionsSetup.SetParseOptions(RazorViewEngineOptions options, CompilationOptions compilationOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DependencyContextRazorViewEngineOptionsSetup.Configure(RazorViewEngineOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.CreateOptions()
   at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorReferenceManager..ctor(ApplicationPartManager partManager, IOptions`1 optionsAccessor)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Comment: Did you get this on any `View`?

Comment: Yes, I have this issue on every single view, for every single action. Static files work just fine.

Comment: Maybe try deleting the `bin` directory from your solution and rebuild.

Comment: Deleting both bin and obj, nothing, same issue. I think it could be environment related.

Comment: Disable and enable again the IIS from Programs and Features

Comment: I'm going to try that, but I do have this problem using both IIS and Kestrel, In any folder, anywhere on my system

Comment: Also update the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` to the latest version. I think it might be related to the Roslyn compiler. The latest version is 2.0

Comment: Well there we are,`Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` solved my problem, I had to get rid of scaffolding to do it, but the app actually works, so... meh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` to the latest version.